# Linux program to quote filename only when necessary?

Tags: ls, filenames, quoting, escape-characters

Consider having these directories and files:

```
$ tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── dir
│   ├── file_normal
│   ├── file with "double quote
│   ├── file with 'single quote
│   ├── file with space
│   └── special!char
├── dir with space
│   ├── file_normal
│   ├── file with "double quote
│   ├── file with 'single quote
│   ├── file with space
│   └── special!char
├── file_normal
├── file with "double quote
├── file with 'single quote
├── file with space
└── special!char
```

`ls` add single quotes or double quotes **only when it is necessary**. Note `dir` and `file_normal` are not quoted.

```
$ ls -1 /tmp/test
dir
'dir with space'
file_normal
'file with "double quote'
"file with 'single quote"
'file with space'
'special!char'
```

`ls` does the same with individual file.

Not to add quotes when not necessary:

```
$ ls "file_normal"
file_normal
$ ( cd dir ; ls "$( realpath file_normal )" )
/tmp/test/dir/file_normal
```

Add quotes only when necessary:

```
$ ls "file with space"
'file with space'
$ ( cd 'dir with space' ; ls "$( realpath file_normal )" )
'/tmp/test/dir with space/file_normal'
```

Consider using `ls` in shell script programs is generally discouraged. Are there any built-in Linux programs that can achieve the same functionality: **Add single or double quotes to a filepath only when necessary?**

Comment: Remember that you don't need to worry about quotes if you are iterating across a set of files with (say) `for item in *` or `find … -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r item`, or even `items=(*.txt)` , where the shell puts file names into variables itself. Just make sure that you double-quote your variables when you use them, e.g. `mv "$item" "$item.old"` rather just `mv $item $item.old`

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisDavies, for the reminder. I am actually writing filenames to files using the command `echo "$fname" > file`. When the file names are properly quoted, users can conveniently copy the file names into command prompts and use them. Quoting is preferred over escaping for the sake of readability. Excessive quoting should be avoided to maintain readability.

Comment: If it's simply for copying and pasting I'd use `printf '%q\n' "fred's files"`

Comment: `ls` does not put quotes around things when you pipe the result (`ls | cat`). This behaviour is only seen when it writes directly to the terminal.  So, when you try to capture the output of `ls`, you will get a very different result to the one you see on screen.

Comment: @PhilipCouling - How about using `ls -d --quoting-style=shell-escape` or `QUOTING_STYLE=shell-escape stat -c %N`, as suggested by muru below? Will those eliminate the uncertainty?

Comment: Perhapse. Though the other question in my mind is "why do you need this". If you specifically want it for presenting to a user then that's fine. The moment you try to use that inside of a shell it's going to break. See the result of this: `x='"a b"' ; for y in $x ; do echo $y ; done`. This prints `"a` and `b"` on seperate lines when you perhapse wanted `a b` on one line, the double quotes get accepted as part of the argument and don't prevent `x` from being split.

Comment: As mentioned in my second comment above, it is used for presenting to the user, and allows the user to copy and use the filename, for example, e.g. `vi 'my file'`. From a code perspective, you may see it as `eval stat "$x"`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: `ls`. Just use it. Like any rule, "don't use ls" will have exceptions where they make sense. This is one of them. First you need to understand *why* using `ls` is discouraged:

- It's used where simple shell globs do the job perfectly well, and often better than `ls` can since the shell will give you the paths as separate words directly without you having to parse `ls`'s output. (It's particularly galling when you see something like `for i in $(ls *.xyz)` instead of `for i in *.xyz`.)
- When trying to get extra information along with filenames, variable column sizes in `ls -l` make that hard to parse. Use `stat` or `find` instead.
- `ls` can make handling of special characters in output tricky (some characters being replaced by `?`, for example).

In this case:

- you apparently *already* have the relevant path, so you're not misusing `ls` to get it where globs would suffice
- you're not using `ls -l` or trying to get any information other than the path
- you *want* the special output that `ls` provides (but `--quoting-style=shell-escape` specifically)

So, just use something like:

```
quoted_path=$(ls -d --quoting-style=shell-escape <some-path>)
```

Just be sure to understand that this isn't *standard*. Somewhat recent versions of GNU ls do it, but busybox ls doesn't (AFAICT), so not all Linux systems will have it.

---

You can also use [GNU stat](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html) for the same thing using the `%N` format specifier:

> - `%N` – Quoted file name with dereference if symbolic link (see below)
>   [...]
>   The ‘`%N`’ format can be set with the environment variable `QUOTING_STYLE`. If that environment variable is not set, the default value is ‘`shell-escape-always`’.

So:

```
quoted_path=$(QUOTING_STYLE=shell-escape stat -c %N <some-path>)
```

The quoting styles for `stat` seem to be the same as for `ls` (I'd bet they use the same functions internally). In this case, the main differentiator seems to be symlink handling: `stat` is probably not  what you want to use if you want to handle symlinks as-is:

```
% QUOTING_STYLE=shell-escape stat -c %N bar$'\n'baz$'\t'xyz
'bar'$'\n''baz'$'\t''xyz' -> 'foo bar'
% ls --quoting-style=shell-escape bar$'\n'baz$'\t'xyz
'bar'$'\n''baz'$'\t''xyz'
```

---

Other options:

- [Bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) with the `Q` quoting operator: `${foo@Q}` will print the contents of the variable `foo` with quoting (but it always adds some quoting, it seems)
- [Bash's `printf` with the `%q` format specifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf) (though it seems to use backslashes in preference to quotes, but doesn't add escaping if not needed)

Comment: Thanks muru. I prefer to stick with POSIX, so `Q` or `%q` are not for me. Thank you for introducing me to the `ls --quoting-style` option and the `QUOTING_STYLE` variable too. I did consider using `stat`, but I was unaware of the [`QUOTING_STYLE` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-the-file-names.html). Do you think using the `stat` method is better than using `ls` in terms of being more lightweight?

Comment: @midnite not really. In this case, I don't think `ls` will be doing anything that `stat` wouldn't. And neither `ls` nor `stat` have these special quoting effects as part of their POSIX spec.